# FXML set percentWidth on target node directly

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Is it possible to set the percentWidth in the target node directly? I tried but im getting many errors if I do so:

```
<GridPane>
  <Button fx:id="node" id="node" text="fooBar"
     GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="always" GridPane.percentWidth="25"/>
</GridPane>
```

that is instead of:

```
   <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="25" />
    </columnConstraints>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is no static `setPercentWidth(Node,  ...)` method in `GridPane` (see [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)).

It wouldn't really make sense to allow this anyway; it would enable you to set different percent widths on different nodes even if they were in the same column. Percent width is inherently a property of a column.

Comment: I see. That you very much for your answer. It makes sense now.